# What is a good strategy to remember to brush my teeth?

Tags: personal-care

I always forget to brush them and I really want to improve. I have to figure out how to remember better because I have gingivitis. Any good strategies?

Comment: Welcome to the site Lolman.  Thank you for appreciating my answer, but generally you shouldn't accept an answer so quickly.  People will often not read a question if it already has an accepted answer.  In the future, consider up-voting (click the up triangle) an answer you like.  Wait a day or two before accepting the answer so that other people will provide alternate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting married worked for me.  My wife is a great life coach. :)

Seriously though, **store your toothbrush in a location where you will notice it**.

For example, after brushing in the morning you could place your toothbrush on your bed pillow so you will notice it at night.

Then after brushing at night, place it in the shower (assuming you shower in the morning).